# How do I get the response code on an HttpClient request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-response-codes

Using the Apache http commons code, the call:

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
```

returns a response object which has a `response.getStatusLine()` method that returns a String that includes the response code. But no method to get the response code as an int.

How can I get the response code? Parsing the string strikes me as fragile as there might be a message with other numbers in it.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `StatusLine`, you can call [`getStatusCode()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode()):

```
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: That's what I get for going from sample code and not looking at the method to realize it was an object and not a string. Thank you.

Comment: Yep it's an object. Conceptually though, it can be thought of as a "string" as the doc mentions: `Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/index.html